# Firewall rules not working for network

Tags: networking, server, firewall, router, policy

I have configured my ubuntu server to be a router and firewall. It has dhcp functionalities and it gives ip addresses to my other two computers. There is an implicit deny in the network. However the implicit deny only works when I try to access the ip of the ubuntu server/router. When I try to contact from this pc to the other it works. Shouldn't the firewall rules apply for the whole network?

Comment: It's really hard to answer on your question. Please give some more details regarding how the network is connected (scheme would be great). Also, attach the table/rules here so we can assist you better.

Comment: I agree with @guyromb, you have fragments of information spread over several questions, but never the complete picture.

Comment: Sorry I am so new at this can you guys just tell me if it is possible to apply the firewall rules for the whole network and not just the host? If so how is it possible? Will I have to use NAT?

Answer (score 1):

No.

When you make your Ubuntu server into a firewall/router, it does become a complete firewall protecting your entire LAN (Local Area Network) from the WAN (Wide Area Network), or internet in general. The quaility of that protection depends on how good and complete your iptables rules set is.

Now, and if I understand correctly, you are asking if your Ubuntu server firewall/router can be used to prevent, in some ways, two computers on your LAN from communicating with each other. No. At least in a typical LAN, those two computers do not need to involve the server at all when they communicate with each other.

Comment: Ok but how will I make sure that all computers pass through this firewall as a gateway?

Comment: Well, first I assume there is no other way to get to/from the internet (WAN), so the packets have to pass through your Ubuntu Server firewall/router. Second I assume in your dhcp.conf file you set the `options routers` line to point to your Ubuntu server firewall/ router. Third, I assume your iptables rule set takes care of it all (which is why we keep asking for your complete listings on your other questions).